# How to use predicates with fetchRequest in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios10, nsfetchrequest

I pass a contact Identifier from Contacts tableview controller to another Location tableview controller. So I  define a delegate ContactSelectionDelegate and implement method userSelectedContact in Location tableview controller and get contactIdentifierString

I am searching the database to find a match for contactIdentifierString and find value for another attribute provider name. This involves searching the whole database. Is there a faster way by assigning a predicate to the context fetchRequest. I thought that would be faster and fewer lines of code.

Can someone suggest how to use predicates with contact fetchRequest?

ContactTableViewController code:

```
protocol ContactSelectionDelegate{
func userSelectedContact(contactIdentifier:NSString)
}

class ContactTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var delegate:ContactSelectionDelegate? = nil

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (delegate != nil){
        let contactDict:NSDictionary = allContacts.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        let identifier = contactDict.object(forKey: "uniqueId")
                   delegate!.userSelectedContact(contactIdentifier: identifier as! NSString)
                  self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
               }
}
```

}

LocationTableViewController code:

```
 class LocationTableViewController: UITableViewController, ContactSelectionDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var contactIdentifierString:NSString = NSString()

 func userSelectedContact(contactIdentifier: NSString) {
    var fetchedResults: [Contact] = []

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        fetchedResults = try context.fetch(Contact.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        print ("fetch task failed")
    }
    if fetchedResults.count > 0 {
        for contact in fetchedResults{
            let aContact:Contact = contact
            if (aContact.uniqueId! == contactIdentifierString as String) {
                providerName.text = aContact.providerName
            }
            else {
                continue
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all get rid of all `NSString` and `NSDictionary` occurrences. This is Swift!. Use the Swift native structs `String` and `Dictionary`.

Second of all put always all *good* code in the `do` scope of a `do - catch` block.

A CoreData predicate has a simple format `attribute == value` which is very similar to `aContact.uniqueId! == contactIdentifierString`:

```
var contactIdentifierString = ""

func userSelectedContact(contactIdentifier: String) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Contact> = Contact.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueId == %@", contactIdentifier)
        let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if let aContact = fetchedResults.first {
           providerName.text = aContact.providerName
        }
    }
    catch {
        print ("fetch task failed", error)
    }

}
```

The code assumes that there is a `NSManagedObject` subclass `Contact` containing

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Contact> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Contact>(entityName: "Contact")
}
```

Comment: I get error Contact on this line:  "Ambiguoius use of fetchrequest".   let fetchRequest = Contact.fetchRequest()

Comment: Changed it to : let req:NSFetchRequest<Contact> = Contact.fetchRequest(). Now I get error: Use of undeclared type NSFetchRequest. Looks like I don’t have NSManagedObject subclasses. So Generated NSManagedObject subclasses for both my entities. I get error on my Contact entity inside  Contact+CoreDataProperties.swift as “Contact is ambiguous for type lookup in this context”. May be the NSManagedObject classes got autogenerated. Circling with errors. Can you pl. explain and how to fix?

Comment: I was assuming that you're using a NSManagedObject subclass because `providerName` is accessed with dot notation. The subclass must contain the method `fetchRequest()`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes it works. Can you explain what is fetchedResults.first.? I am going to accept your solution as answer. But I thought If I accept you may not be able to reply my question. But I will accept it

Comment: A CoreData fetch returns always an array and this kind of fetch request is supposed to return only one item on success. The line `if let .... .first` gets the first item in the array if the array is not empty (`first` returns an optional).

Comment: full of typo mistakes

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard Thanks for pointing out. I updated the answer.