# How to fetch particular range data from CoreData in ios swift3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch

Hi I was succeeded in fetching data from coreData by using the below code.

```
class func fetchObject() -> [User]?{
    let context = getContext()
    var user: [User]? = nil
    do{
        user = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
        return user
    }catch{
        return user
    }
}
```

Now I want to fetch a data in particular range.

For example I was saving some records with age as one column in that. Now I want to get the only 10 to 20 age persons from that coreData table. How can I achieve that. Please some one help me.Because I am new to ios.

Comment: pass NSEntityDescrition to fetchrequest for any query e.g. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/core-data-queries-using-expressions/

Comment: Please use predicate after in fetch request you use. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41641947/1142743 for more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to use predicate to filter out data.

```
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "<AgeKey> <= %d && <AgeKey> >= %d", 10,20)
    user = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```